# Posting data from one website to another hidden behind AD credentials

Tags: authentication, iis, webserver, credentials, http-status-code-401

I have two websites, both hosted with IIS. and both on different web servers.

On website A someone will submit a form. Website A then sends POST data to website B to let it know that a form has been submitted, this will then use SignalR to let the relevant users know that the form was submitted.

The problem that I face is that Website B requires authentication, so when the request hits the controller it responds with "*401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.*".

On the controller that should receive the request I have added an [AllowAnonymous] header, however this apparently isn't enough.

As an experiment I tried adding my own network credentials in the request I was sending through Postman but this didn't work and I would prefer not to do that anyway!

Perhaps I need to use a different approach, but I'm not sure what I would do to get the required outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You may have RequireAuthorization() for all endpoints in your SignalR startup:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub", options =>
            {
                options.Transports =
                HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
                //HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
                //| HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents;
            }).RequireAuthorization();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Our application is set up a little differently we are using the IAppBuilder interface which doesn't seem to contain endpoints - Sorry my first exposure to using SignalR! However I do now have a new line of investigation to pursue.